# How can I separate these objects

Tags: modeling, objects

[image]

I've tried to clear parent, but I can't select them individually at all. These are somehow one object, even though I used two different planes to create them in edit mode.

[image]

Even in the top right corner, only one plane shows up.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The editor in the top right corner is called the Outliner, it can be opened and moved anywhere.

The reason it's showing your model as a single object is because you "*used two different planes to create them in edit mode*": when you add primitives in Edit Mode, they are added in the current active object's data block, they are not added as a new object. You would need to be in Object Mode for that to happen.

To turn them into two individual objects, go to edit mode, press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then <kbd>P</kbd> > Separate "*By Lose Parts*".

Comment: The question mentions "*These are somehow one object even though I used two different planes to create them in edit mode*". There was no accidental object joining, there were never two objects to begin with. When you add primitives in edit mode, it adds them inside the active object's mesh data, it doesn't add an extra object in the scene.

Comment: @L0Lock Ok I will update the answer. Apologies.

Comment: @L0Lock please look at the changes I had made during editing.(Or did you?) I had written the answer in a way that a beginner like him could understand. Some of the corrections are necessary but since we edited at almost the same time the part where I did a little of a making it easy thingy was gone. (If you haven't seen that edited version of mine) Could you please make the changes? (I am not that great at formatting an answer so it would be better that you do it)

Comment: I don't think the change is necessary, the information is clear and to the point. But you are entirely free to edit if you wish.

Comment: Yes thank you I got it.